# TRIGGER tU_DEDPARM_OEFix compiled Warning: execution completed with warning

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am running below create trigger query in Oracle :-

```
SQL>CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tU_DEDPARM_OEFix 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON DED_PARM FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN    
  UPDATE DED_PARM SET  
     DED_PARM.OVRD_DED_AM = COALESCE(i.OVRD_DED_AM,0.00), 
     DED_PARM.OVRD_DED_PC = COALESCE(i.OVRD_DED_PC,0.00000)    
       FROM   DED_PARM AS d INNER JOIN inserted AS i  
         ON (i.INTERNAL_EMPL_ID=d.INTERNAL_EMPL_ID AND 
            i.APPOINTMENT_ID=d.APPOINTMENT_ID AND 
            i.DEDTYP_CD=d.DEDTYP_CD AND  
            i.EFFECTIVE_DT=d.EFFECTIVE_DT) 
  END; /
```

After execution of the query i faced below error :-

> TRIGGER tU_DEDPARM_OEFix compiled Warning: execution completed with
>   warning.

Then i ran the below query to see the compilation errors

> SQL>show error Errors for TRIGGER TU_DEDPARM_OEFIX;

Below are the errors :-

> 5/3            PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 2/3
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 10/4           PLS-00103: Encountered
>   the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
>   null pragma raise return select update while with    
>        <<
>   continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Can somebody help me to prepare correct query. FYI- The trigger is created but it is created with compilation errors that i showed above.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid syntax for update in Oracle. I'm not sure what `inserted` do in MSSQL (`:new` or `:old`) but I think this is Oracle statement for that trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tU_DEDPARM_OEFix 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON DED_PARM FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
update DED_PARM d SET 
  OVRD_DED_AM = COALESCE(:new.OVRD_DED_AM,0), 
  OVRD_DED_PC = COALESCE(:new.OVRD_DED_PC,0)
where INTERNAL_EMPL_ID = :new.INTERNAL_EMPL_ID and
      APPOINTMENT_ID = :new.APPOINTMENT_ID and
      DEDTYP_CD = :new.DEDTYP_CD and
      EFFECTIVE_DT = :new.EFFECTIVE_DT;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But if i put semicolon (;) after  DED_PARM.OVRD_DED_PC = COALESCE(:new.OVRD_DED_PC,0);
(before FORM) 
i am facing below error :-
5/3            PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge

Comment: i guess, i should not put semicolon before FORM otherwise i am still facing the same errors after putting your code.@ Kacper

Comment: You don't need from at all there. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm#i2112182 @AshutoshBajpai

Comment: @AshutoshBajpai Try now. I've edited my answer to contain full trigger statement. You can also have a look on docs for triggers: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm

Comment: Hey, Thanks. It is working fine for me now. Actually i have converted the sql query in Oracle that's why this misunderstanding happened..